How do I correctly implement control for GUI in raspberry pi 4
Here I have these code:
//the variables and struct I uses and struct definition 
int menu_flag = 0;     // initialised menu flag to 0
int selected_item = 0; // selected item flag to 0
int selected_difficulty = 0;
menu_item game_difficulties[] = {
    {"DIFFICULTY: NORMAL", 265, 440},
    {"DIFFICULTY: HARD", 265, 440}};
menu_item menu_items[] = {
    {"NEW GAME", 430, 365, handle_game_mode},
    {"GAME DIFFICULTY", 450, 440, select_difficulty, game_difficulties},
    {"EXIT GAME", 450, 520, _exit_game},
};

//struct definition from a header file
typedef struct 
{
    const char* item_string;
    int x;
    int y;
    void (*action)(void);
    struct menu_item *sub_menu;
}menu_item;

//draw the menu
void draw_general_menu()
{
  drawString(380, 240, "TETRIS", COLOR_RED, 3);

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(menu_items) / sizeof(menu_item); i++)
  {
    drawString(menu_items[i].x, menu_items[i].y, menu_items[i].item_string, 0xFFFFFF, 1);
    if (i == selected_item)
    {
      // Highlight the selected item
      uart_dec(selected_item);
      print("\n");
      if (selected_item == 1)
      { // highlight item number 1
        drawLineWithThicknessARGB32(779, 430, 779, 480, 0xFFFFFF, 1); // Right line of difficulty
        drawLineWithThicknessARGB32(254, 430, 254, 480, 0xFFFFFF, 1); // Left line of difficulty 
      }
      else
          {// highlight item number 0 and 2
        drawLineWithThicknessARGB32(menu_items[i].x - 20, menu_items[i].y - 20, menu_items[i].x - 20, menu_items[i].y + 20, COLOR_WHITE, 1);   // left line
        drawLineWithThicknessARGB32(menu_items[i].x + 140, menu_items[i].y - 20, menu_items[i].x + 140, menu_items[i].y + 20, COLOR_WHITE, 1); // right line
      }
    }
    else
    {
      drawLineWithThicknessARGB32(menu_items[i].x - 20, menu_items[i].y - 20, menu_items[i].x - 20, menu_items[i].y + 20, COLOR_BLACK, 1);
      drawLineWithThicknessARGB32(menu_items[i].x + 140, menu_items[i].y - 20, menu_items[i].x + 140, menu_items[i].y + 20, COLOR_BLACK, 1);
    }
  }
}

//logic to move between items on menu
void handle_menu()
{
  draw_general_menu();
  while (!menu_flag)
  {
    
      _uart_scanning_callback();

      if (_is_enter_or_space_command())
      {
        menu_items[selected_item].action();
        
      }
      else if (_is_up_command() && !menu_cmd_delay)
          { 
         selected_item = max(0, selected_item - 1);
        draw_general_menu();
    
      }
      else if (_is_down_command() && !menu_cmd_delay) 
      {
         selected_item = min(sizeof(menu_items) 
         / sizeof(menu_item) - 1, 
        selected_item + 1);
    
        draw_general_menu();
      }
    }
    if (should_exit_game_mode)
    {
      menu_flag = 1;
      //menu_cmd_delay_clear_callback();
    }
  }

When I test it on QEMU, it will starts at "NEW GAME" and then if I choose to go up or down, it will go to the last item or the first item, highlight both item 0 (first) and item 1 or the last item (2) and item 1, instead of just highlighting one item after I move up or down using w and s key. What could be the problem here and how can I fix it so that when I move up or down, it will highlight only one item at a time ?
